# Python global environment screwed up

Tags: python

So, I've been toying around with python environments and I think i screwed mine up.

So when I ran python in shell, it would tell me i'm running on 2.7

I'm on windows 10, and i need a python switcher for my next project so i download pywin and used pywin to switch it to 3.5

the command i used was

```
pywin setdefault 3.5
```

now when i type python it says

```
python is not recognized as an internal or external command.
```

but py produces

```
Python 2.7.12
```

Now i can't use pip, easy_install, virtualenv

all of these commands i used to use, i suddenly no longer have access to them.

I tried switching back

but it wont even recognize pywin anymore.

Comment: Start a new `cmd` console. And display your environment variables. Check the `PATH` and `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: lol, starting a new command prompt did the trick.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE That should probably be an answer

Comment: Answer below is also good, also, try using python3 and python to differentiate between python 3.5 and python 2.7. -- instead of using "python switcher"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to check which Python version is executed is to check your environment variables. Another way of checking this is using the which command. (open cmd and run `which python`).

But, first you need to start a new `cmd` prompt to ensure your environment variables are not altered.

On Windows, but also any OS, you need to check the `PATH` and `PYTHONPATH` variables.

For Windows, follow the recommandations available in the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/using/windows.html#configuring-python).

If you're not very experienced with working with windows, installations, and other similar things, I would recommend that you uninstall python, delete all versions/folders containing python (compiled) files (those that were installed with python, not the ones you've written) and then reinstall python. The installer should re-set the path variable to the correct location.